# How to run python script on terminal (ubuntu)?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I'm new with python, I've been learning for a few weeks. However now I've just changed my OS and I'm now using ubuntu and I can't run any script on my terminal.

I made sure to have the `#!/usr/bin/env python`
but when I go to the terminal and type, for example `python test.py`
the terminal shows an error message like this

> python: can't open file 'test.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

what do I do?
I must save the file in any specific folder to make it run on terminal?

Comment: I will just add a smal precision, if you use `#!/usr/bin/env python` you can just type ./test.py to execute your script as Terminal will take account of your header and use python to launch the script. But before you have to change execution permission by doing `chmod +x test.py`. I understand it can be a bit special for a beginner but you will appreciate this in the future ;)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This error:

> python: can't open file 'test.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Means that the file "test.py" doesn't exist. (Or, it does, but it isn't in the current working directory.)

> I must save the file in any specific folder to make it run on terminal?

No, it can be where ever you want. However, if you just say, "test.py", you'll need to be in the directory containing test.py.

Your terminal (actually, the shell in the terminal) has a concept of "Current working directory", which is what directory (folder) it is currently "in".

Thus, if you type something like:

```
python test.py
```

`test.py` needs to be in the current working directory. In Linux, you can change the current working directory with `cd`. You might want a [tutorial](https://www.google.com/search?q=terminal+tutorial) if you're new. (Note that the first hit on that search for me is [this YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Vl4rpZVA6I). The author in the video is using a Mac, but both Mac and Linux use `bash` for a shell, so it should apply to you.)

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'm a very beignner with Terminal as well, so I got stuck on it. My problem was already solved..
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Set the PATH as below:

---

In the csh shell − type `setenv PATH "$PATH:/usr/local/bin/python"` and press Enter.

In the bash shell (Linux) − type `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin/python"` and press Enter.

In the sh or ksh shell − type `PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin/python"` and press Enter.

Note − `/usr/local/bin/python` is the path of the Python directory

---

now run as below:

```
-bash-4.2$ python test.py

Hello, Python!
```

Answer (score 0):

Save your python file in a spot where you will be able to find it again. Then navigate to that spot using the command line (cd /home/[profile]/spot/you/saved/file) or go to that location with the file browser. If you use the latter, right click and select "Open In Terminal." When the terminal opens, type "sudo chmod +x Yourfilename." After entering your password, type "python ./Yourfilename" which will open your python file in the command line. Hope this helps!

*Running Linux Mint*

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, Im a newbie myself and I had this issue:

./hello.py: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `"Hello World"'
./hello.py: line 1:`print("Hello World")'

I added the file header for the python 'deal' as #!/usr/bin/python

Then simple executed the program with './hello.py'

Comment: A good answer is already there. This is an unnecessary addition.

Answer (score -9):

First create the file you want, with any editor like vi or gedit. And save with a `.py` extension. In that the first line should be

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Comment: The original poster mentions that #!/usr/bin/env python is in the `test.py` file.

Comment: The answer as originally posted had a space between `#` and `!` which would make it invalid. I fixed this but am voting to delete this as superfluous anyway.